# Someone from Chutz Laaretz cooking for Israeli on the second day of Yom Tov

Tags: eretz-yisrael, yom-tov, chutz-laaretz

When I was writing this (PTIJ) [answer](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/100518/11532), I assumed that someone from outside Israel can't cook for someone from Israel on the second day of Yom Tov.  I didn't realize until afterwards that I couldn't think of a source and wasn't sure if it's true.

Was I correct?  Or was I inadvertently making it up?

(Maybe someone who's not obligated in this particular day doesn't count as לכם?)

Comment: to further complicate, is there going to be a difference if the location is chutz laaretz or erez yisroel?

Comment: Considering that the 2nd day is just strict b/c of uncertainty, *ma nafshach*, if it is Yom Tov, the Israeli is also obligated and therefore it is permitted to cook for him, and if it isn't, everyone's allowed to cook for everyone.

Comment: @Loewian https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/10446/11532 it's not necessarily so simple